# Generate only 2 specific numbers using Math.random() in javascript

Tags: javascript

A function in Javascript which will return either 0 or 100 value using math.random function.
I'm trying to pass that value to borderRadius to get a square-circle effect randomly.
Thanks !!!

Comment: So, what is your question? What have you done, where is your code? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
function func(){

  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 100;

}
```

Comment: There's one in every crowd, it's you @RobG :p

Comment: Just need to turn the `>` around. :-0

Comment: @RobG Some people just want to watch the world burn

Answer (score 1):

No if needed - just do it:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function vv()
{
    if (Math.random() * 100 > 50)
        return 100;
    else
        return 0;
}
```